# Criteria for a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If the criteria for a subgroup of a group is to be non-empty and have inverse elements for every element in the subgroup, then why don't the subgroups of D<sub>4</sub> have inverse elements for each element in them?

[image: Lattice of D4's generators of subgroups of]

[image: Subgroup of D4]

Ex.: The elements of the subgroups of D<sub>4</sub> are

{1} = <1>

D<sub>8</sub> = <r, s>

{1, r²} = <r²>

{1, s} = < s >

{1, r²s} = <r²s>

{1, rs} = < rs >

{1, r³s} = <r³s>

{1, r², rs, r³s} = <r², rs>

{1, r, r², r³} = < r >

{1, r², s, r²s} = <r², s>

Where are the inverse elements of each of them being displayed?

Comment: In the elements for each of the subgroup you have listed the inverses, only that they are not written as $g^{-1}$. For example in the third subgroup of the list we have that $(r^2)^{-1}=r^2$ given that $r^2r^2=r^4=1$. In a similar way you can verify that each of the subgroups of the list contains its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your summary of the subgroup criterion is incorrect. It is not enough that the subset be nonempty and contain the inverse of every element in the set. You also need that the set be closed under multiplication. That is:

> Let $G$ be a group, written multiplicatively. A subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup if and only if:
>
> 1. $H\neq \varnothing$; and
> 2. If $x,y\in H$, then $xy\in H$; and
> 3. If $x\in H$, then $x^{-1}\in H$.

Second, you are also incorrect that the subgroups of $D_4$ don't have the inverses of their elements. Yes, they do.

For example, $\{1,r^2\}$ is a subgroup. the inverse of $1$ is $1$, which is in the set; the inverse of $r^2$ is $r^2$, which is also in the set. It contains the inverse of every element in the set.

The set $\{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$ is a subgroup; it contains the inverse of all its elements, since $1^{-1}=1$, $r^{-1}=r^3$, $(r^2)^{-1}=r^2$, and $(r^3)^{-1}=r$.

Just because you do not see a "${}^{-1}$" doesn't mean the inverse isn't there.

Comment: Despite knowing about the product criterion of the elements within the subgroup, I forgot to mention it. But not being so strict, it wasn't clear to me about the inverse element.  Studying alone with just books is more complicated. But, asking one more question, now about the issue of isomorphism between subgroups of the symmetric group and the dihedral group. If D<sub>4</sub> is isomorphic to S<sub>4</sub> and S<sub>4</sub> has order 4!, why doesn't D<sub>4</sub> have 24 subgroups too?

Comment: Does it have to do with the order of the elements? Ex.: could {1, r³} and {1, r², sr³, sr} be subgroups of D<sub>4</sub>?

Comment: @eduardo Please use MathJax for math formulas in StackExchange. Here is [a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742)

Comment: @eduardo: $S_4$ is **not** isomorphic to $D_4$. Where do you get that idea? $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$, but $D_n$ is not isomorphic to $S_n$ for any larger $n$. $\{1,r^3\}$ is not a subgroup of $D_4$ because it is neither closed under products (as $r^3r^3 = r^2\notin\{1,r^3\}$) nor inverses ($(r^3)^{-1}=r\notin\{1,r^3\}$). Your other example is already in your list, as $sr^3=rs$ and $sr=r^3s$, so $\{1,r^2,sr^3,sr\}=\{1,r^2,rs,r^3s\}=\langle r^2,s\rangle$, the eight group in your list.

Comment: However, when it is said that r³s is its own inverse in the subgroup {1, r³s}, then why does there exist r² in the subgroup {1, rs, r³s, r²}? Doesn't the order of the factors in an element of the dihedral group change the way the polygon moves? Ex.: rs ≠ sr but rs = sr^(-1), and in this subgroup, specifically D_4, the operation between r³s and rs results in r². Therefore, the joining of the two elements results in a third element r² and which, in this way, has the element r² as its own inverse element.

Comment: Can't there be another subgroup other than {1, r², r³s, rs} that counts in the order of the factors of an element? So, {1, r³s, sr} ≤ D_4? Or does it not exist?

Comment: @eduardo Please use mathjax.

Comment: @eduardo I have no idea what "that counts the order of the factors of an element" means.  It is nonsense. In a group, what is a "factor of an element"? If $x\in G$, then for all $y$ there exists $z$ such that $x=yz$.

Comment: When I say factor, I refer to the combination of reflections and translations.  r and s are factors of r²s for example.

Comment: @eduardo And I'm telling you that this is a terrible way to talk and think about it, because it means nothing, so you should stop saying that. Your questions show complete confusion, probably *because* you are trying to think about the elements of $D_4$ in ways that are just wrong. That $\{1,r^3s\}$ is a subgroup follows because it is nonempty, closed under products, and closed under inverses. That $\{1,r^2,r^3s,rs\}$ is **also** a subgroup is likewise true, and this fact is irrelevant to the first being a subgroup. No subgroup of $D_4$ can have exactly 3 elements (Lagrange's Theorem).

Comment: @eduardo You have the complete list of subgroups. Check for yourself that they are all subgroups. Then check for yourself that no other subset will be a subgroup, either because it fails to be closed under products, fails to be closed under inverses, or is empty. Check them, think it through, work it through.

Comment: Thank you very much!!